# выводить массив через Ajax на PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

необходимо при клике выводить массив через Ajax на PHP. в моем случае PHP выводит NULL. нужно именно через Ajax и PHP

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="click" class="stone">click</div>
    <?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    var_dump($data);
    ?>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $("#click").on("click", function(){
                var data=["a", "b", "c"];
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
                   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",

                        data: {data : jsonString},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(){
                            alert("OK"+jsonString);
                        }
                    });
               });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $data[] =$_POST['data']; print_r($data); так попробуй вначале

Comment: выводит Array ( [0] => )

Comment: @АринаЛаврова обработчик post-запроса нужно обернуть в if-условие ``if (isset($_POST['data']) {....}```

Comment: @Jigius я пробовала, тогда вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Сделал рабочий пример использования ajax-запроса для отправки со страницы данных на сервер(PHP), получения от него новых данных и вывода их на странице.

Это должно помочь разобраться в вашем вопросе.

**Описание**:

- На странице пользователь вводит через запятую значения и нажимает кнопку.
- Клик-событие вызывает ajax-запрос (post + json) к php-скрипту на сервере, который передает в параметре `data` массив значений, полученных с помощью преобразования значений введеной на странице строки в массив(разделитель - символ запятой).
- PHP-скрипт проверяет факт того, что совершен POST-запрос - значение параметра `data` супер-массива `$_POST` определено и если это так, то извлекает значения переданного массива `data`, добавляет в него два значения `three` и `four`, возвращает его в виде json-ответа и завершает свою работу.
- Когда ответ от php-скрипта сервера получен, то полученные данные из массива преобразовываются в строку и отображаются на странице.

**index.php**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    echo header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (!is_array($_POST['data'])) {
        $data = array();
    } else {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
    }
    $data[] = "three!";
    $data[] = "four!";
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Прогоняем данные через AJAX-запрос</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Входные данные на сервер:<br>
        <textarea class="input">one, two</textarea><br>
        <button id="click" class="stone">Отправить!</button><br>
        <hr>
        Выходные данные от сервера:<br>
        <textarea class="output"></textarea><br>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#click")
            .on("click", function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {data : $(".input").val().split(/\s*,\s*/)}
                    })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        if (!$.isArray(data)) {
                            alert("Ошибка! полученные данные не корректны!");
                        } else {
                            $(".output").val(data.toString());
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (er) {
                        alert("Ошибка! Что-то пошло не так :(");
                    });
               });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо болшое! многие вещи прояснились. А если нужно сделать так, чтобы массив вводился на одной странице - index.php , а  передавался на другую, например, show.php. То есть мне нужно получить этот массив для последующей записи в файл.

Comment: Обработчик запроса  переносите в show.php , а также меняете url параметр у ajax-запроса.

Comment: я сделала, как вы сказали. но при этом у меня не получается вывести массив на другой странице. выводится null

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы отправляете `ajax` запрос на ту же страницу, она уже отрисована и `php` отработал. Что бы пыха подобрала данные из массива `$_post` ей (пыхе, которая на сервере) нужно послать запрос на новую отрисовку страницы с данными из массива `$_post`. В вашем примере нет необходимости во вставке фрагмента php кода, достаточно результат подставить динамически тем же `js`

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#someelement').append(data);
```

Что бы пыхой ловить $_POST, надо перезагружать страницу. Это не `ajax кейс`. 
Именно в вашем случае нужна форма. Если вам надо отправить данные на файл-обработчик, что-то сделать с данными и вернуть некий результат обратно и всё это без перезагрузки страницы - тогда `ajax`

Comment: Вообще ниче не понятно.